# sql basic if else conditions

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have this table:

`|car |house|`
`|2010|2012 |`
`|2005|2004 |`
`|2003|2003 |`
`|2006|     |`

and I need to create this table from it:

`|car |house|result|`
`|2010|2012 |after |`
`|2005|2004 |before|`
`|2003|2003 |after |`
`|2006|     |x     |`

cases: 
`car`<`house`  `result`=before
`car`>`house` `result`=after
`car`=`house`  `result`=after
`house` is empty -> `result`=x

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `CASE EXPRESSION` :

```
SELECT t.car,t.house,
       CASE WHEN t.house >= t.car THEN 'AFTER'
            WHEN t.house < t.car THEN 'BEFORE'
            ELSE 'x'
       END as result
FROM YourTable t
```

**EDIT:** To join this to another table :

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT t.car,t.house,
           CASE WHEN t.house >= t.car THEN 'AFTER'
                WHEN t.house < t.car THEN 'BEFORE'
                ELSE 'x'
           END as result
    FROM YourTable t) s
JOIN Another_Table tt
 ON(s.result = tt.Column)
```

Comment: with this code I get only data output with this new column(result), but how can I join this column in to t. table ? thank you